# Cassandra initial token in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra

I followed the following steps to migrate all the data from one cluster to a completely new cluster:
http://datascale.io/cloning-cassandra-clusters-fast-way/

I managed to get all the data to the new cluster, the servers see each other, nodetool status reports all nodes as `UN`. However, I do have a question, in one of the paragraph the `initial_token` values are taken from the nodes and copied one on one to the new servers, and I had to add `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.load_ring_state=false"`. I suppose the `JVM_OPTS` can be discarded now, but I'm not so sure about the `initial_tokens`?

My entire configuration is managed by Puppet, and I'm now unsure whether the `initial_tokens` are needed once the cluster has been populated and initialized? The manifests are very clean, and this would add unnecessary complications since the values of `inital_tokens` are unique to each node. I want to be sure, since this is my first time dealing with Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that once the cluster has been initialized, the `initial_token` value gets written somewhere inside the Cassandra structure. Even after restarting the entire new cluster without the `initial_token` directive, the cluster works fine and I get the exact same tokens with the same procedure I got them on the old cluster.

Looks like after things are stabilized, you can remove the `initial_token` from the `cassandra.yaml` file.

Comment: Crawling through Cassandra docs, this is indeed a good question, and nice to find some concrete answer. Thanks for saving me from setting up yet-another-labs ...

Comment: Yes after the node has complete the initial bootstrap, the tokens are saved in the system.local table.